# Web performance test does nothing

Tags: automated-testing, performance, browser-automation, visualstudio

I'm trying to set up a web performance test in Visual Studio 2013 (the online tutorials seem targeted at earlier versions of VS).

I right click in my solution explorer and select Add ... then Web Performance test.

Immediately an IE browser window pops up, and in the background IDE I see a button saying "stop recording". Okay, so I'm recording, right?

I click through a few things on our web app, then I click "stop recording" in VS and nothing happens.

The panel where I would expect to surface some kind of activity seems blank!

[image]

When I click run test it immediately says "Passed". Doesn't appear to be doing anything.

I tried running this from a separate instance of Visual Studio as well as from the same solution as our web app.

Also, when I click "Show recorder" nothing happens.

I'm running VisualStudio 2013 Update 4.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was buried in [some MSDN documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119144530/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/16/using-internet-explorer-11-and-not-able-to-record-a-web-performance-test-successfully.aspx) that was challenging to reach via Google.

Also ... don't forget to enable the test tool. Might have to check a couple places.